# Cache clearing takes too long: What can I do to improve it?

Tags: database

Everytime I clear all the caches, the process takes too long. This is from the log to a prod site I am currently working with.

> 368829 | [someuser] | dbname | Query | 3376 | updating | `DELETE FROM cache_page WHERE expire != 0 AND expire <= 1370891317`

As you can see, it was executing for 3376 seconds. I am wondering if this is a known issue, or it is simply because there is just too much in that table.

Also, is there anything I can do to improve this?

Answer (score 1):

I have a pure MySQL approach to clearing the `cache_page` table quickly.

```
use dbname
ALTER TABLE cache_page RENAME cache_pageoff;
CREATE TABLE cache_pagenew LIKE cache_pageoff;
INSERT INTO cache_pagenew
    SELECT * FROM cache_pageoff
    WHERE expire > 1370891317
;
ALTER TABLE cache_pagenew RENAME cache_page;
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_pageoff;
DROP TABLE cache_pageoff;
```

This script will do the following:

- take the `cache_page` offline
- create a new `cache_page`
- load the new `cache_page` with the most current data
- put the new `cache_page` back online
- remove the old `cache_page`

Give it a Try !!!

BTW the reason the process is taking long has to do with the range of the delete and the storage engine is use.

- If your `cache_page` tables is using the MyISAM storage engine, the `DELETE` query would be traversing almost the entire table and deleting each row.
- If your `cache_page` tables is using the InnoDB storage engine, this is orders or magnitude worse that MyISAM. Why? All the rows you are deleting are stored in the [Undo Logs within ibdata1](http://www.scribd.com/doc/31337494/XtraDB-InnoDB-internals-in-drawing).

  - When the `DELETE` query has completed successfully, all the Undo Logs for the `cache_page` table are purged.
  - If the `DELETE` query is interrupted by a rollback operation, all the Undo Logs are used to restore the `cache_page` table in its original state. If `cache_page` is InnoDB, I strongly recommend not interrupting the `DELETE`  query. Let it goes its full course.

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try. We also have tungesten replicator on prod servers. Could it be adding to the problem? because on Testing servers the issue is not as bad.